# INTO error in SELECT while creating stored procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, pls-00428

I am trying to create stored procedure where I want to join two tables and save the result into one of the tables, but I am getting INTO clause is required error.

This is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DiorItemMaster
AS
SELECT *FROM pcdo_dior_item_master
INNER JOIN pcdo_itemdata on pcdo_itemdata.vpn = pcdo_dior_item_master.vpn;
GO;
```

ERROR:

> Error(4,1): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Answer (score 2):

You have a query that selects columns from a table in your pl/sql block. What do you want to do with the result of that query ? You cannot *just select* and not do anything with the results in pl/sql (you can in sql). Oracle expects that you to store the results of that select in variables. That can be done using the `SELECT INTO` clause.
Example (based on sample schema emp/dept):

```
DECLARE
  l_emp emp%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT e.* INTO l_emp FROM emp e WHERE e.ename = 'KING';
END;
/
```

Note that you can `SELECT INTO` individual columns and into rows. You cannot use `SELECT INTO` arrays.

A couple of other remarks about your code:

- You perform a `SELECT *` from a table with a join to another table without using aliases. This will return all columns from both tables. It is a lot more readable to prefix the "*" with a table alias like in the example.
- The `GO;` is not part of the oracle syntax - this will cause a compilation error.